# HTML Align header image to the center not working

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I'm trying to align to the center as a header that is not working, here is my code, help is appreciated because anything else I find online is currently not working.

```css
.center {   
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<body class="news">
  <div id="geheel">
    <div id="header"><img src="Images/turbinezaal9-2-2.jpg"/></div>
</body>
```

Comment: you are not using the css class `.center` in your html snippet. seems like you would need to add it to the `img` (i.e. `<img class="center" />`)

Comment: Thank you very much u/zgood

Answer (score 2):

That's because you haven't the center used  tag in your code, here's a working example!

```css
.center {   
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<body class="news">
  <div id="geheel">
    <div id="header"><center><img src="Images/turbinezaal9-2-2.jpg"/></center></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to use the class .center

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the  tag

```css
.center {   
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<body class="news">
  <div id="geheel">
    <div id="header"><center><img src="Images/turbinezaal9-2-2.jpg"/></center></div>
</body>
```